# Feed data between 2 persons on Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-timeline

Is it possible to get the data posted by a person on the timeline of one other person on Facebook?

If it is, how could I do it? Do I need to use FQL queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you things that someone else has posted on the active user's timeline with FQL:

```
SELECT actor_id, created_time, message, attachment FROM stream 
   WHERE source_id=me() AND actor_id != me()
```

Comment: Is it possible to get this between 2 dates? And does it retrieve the data where the source_id was tagged?

Comment: Yes, you could by adding more conditions to the `WHERE` part of the query. Take a look at the `stream` table documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream

Comment: Is it possible to get the same result using graph api?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Graph API doesn't allow you to filter results on a specific condition like FQL does.

Comment: FQL isn't buggy. The `stream` table is deliberately hobbled to restrict what you can get. The equivalent Graph API `/feed` endpoint has the same limitations.

Comment: But it never returns the LIMIT of items that I specify. And If I put a range of one month, I only get like 10 results that in reality, only ranges a week.